# Make list in decsending order of length of dataset

Tags: r

I have 3 dataset namely `pc_dat`, `rf_dat` & `co_dat`:

```
pc_dat 
User Val
A     21
B     22

rf_dat 
User Val
A     41
B     52
C     45

co_dat
User Val
A     89
```

If I get following:

```
length(pc_dat) 
[1] 2

length(rf_dat) 
[1] 3

length(co_dat) 
[1] 1
```

Then I want to create a list which will automatically takes datasets with descending order of lengths i.e. `rf_dat` will appear first, `pc_dat` second and `co_dat` third as shown below:

```
list_data = list(rf_dat, pc_dat, co_dat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list` using `ls` and `mget`, then `order` in descending by getting the number of rows in the `list`

```
list_data <- mget(ls(pattern ="_dat$"))
list_data[order(-sapply(list_data, nrow))]
#$rf_dat
#  User Val
#1    A  41
#2    B  52
#3    C  45

#$pc_dat
#  User Val
#1    A  21
#2    B  22

#$co_dat
#  User Val
#1    A  89
```

Just to be safe, `order` also have `decreasing = TRUE` argument